# Bootstrap 5 Image sizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I wish to create a login screen like Twitter.
[www.twitter.com](http://www.twitter.com)

On the left of the screen I wish to have a full-size image and a form on the right.

I want the image to be right aligned so the left-hand side will be cropped if the screen is too narrow.

I am using Bootstrap 5 and my image is full height however it has lost its proportions.

```
  <div class="container vh-100">
    <div class="row vh-100">
      <div class="col-6">
        <img src="../assets/login.jpg" class="img-fluid float-end vh-100" alt="login">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <!-- Form goes here -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      This is the footer
    </div>
  </div>
```

Edit: In addition to creating an image full height, I see Twitter has a footer so the combination of the image & footer are full height, not just the image.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `vh-100` because it will be force `height` to `100vh` that your image will be lost its proportions.

Next: You don't need `img-fluid` but you need CSS `object-fit: cover;` with full `width` and `height` to `100%`. (Or maybe change width to your need.) The `object-fit: cover;` will make your image stretch depend on size (width, height) without lost proportions. Read more about this on [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp).

However, I couldn't find any class from Bootstrap that work as `object-fit: cover;`. So, you need to manually write it in your own CSS file.
I added class name `my-brand-image` and custom CSS there.

Your full HTML and CSS will be:

```css
.my-brand-image {
    object-position: center;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="container vh-100">
    <div class="row vh-100">
      <div class="col-6">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x800/000000/fff" class="img-fluid float-end my-brand-image" alt="login">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <!-- Form goes here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See it in action on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jot7nLva/).